# C++: GUI libraries for embedding into an interpreter

Tags: c++, user-interface, interpreter, embedding

I've got my interpreter up and running - quite bug-free and stable for now - now I want to add some visual options to my language to play around.

- What is a good GUI library easy to use and mainly easy to embed and "link" to my programming language?
- What general rules do I have to follow?

I'm currently on XP with Microsoft Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your language and it's properties. For example, if you can only expose C-style functions, then the default WinAPI supports this style. If you can do the whole C++ classes malarky, then you could do MFC, GDI+, WIC, etc.

Ultimately, if you want something easy to embed, it's simpler to write good embedding code than worry about what you're going to embed.

Answer (score 0):

In various posts I have seen regarding UI Libraries QT and WxWidgets seem to be popular.

[Look here for a list of features](http://home.pacbell.net/atai/guitool/)

Answer (score 0):

Check out the fast light toolkit (FLTK) at http://fltk.org. From that website:

FLTK (pronounced "fulltick") is a cross-platform C++ GUI toolkit for UNIX®/Linux® (X11), Microsoft® Windows®, and MacOS® X. FLTK provides modern GUI functionality without the bloat and supports 3D graphics via OpenGL® and its built-in GLUT emulation.